# button and onclick - Html, javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Please this button below does not fire

```
 <button onclick="download(this, .mp4)" type="button">Download</button>
```

I am thinking the onclick tag is not firing what could be the cause & solutions thanks

Here is the javascript code that recieves the fucntion

```
function download(object, ext) {
    alert('I was called');
}
```

I changed it to this because i wanted to be sure it was not a syntax error in my function causing the error ...

Here is the php code

```
$ext = "." . $extension[1];
echo "<button type='button' onclick='download(this, $ext)'>Download</button>";
```

This works:

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick='download(this, \"$ext\")'>Download</button>";
                                        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: have you checked your console for errors ("such as unexpected token .")? Have you added an alert/console.log in the download function to verify that it's not getting hit? More details needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your `download()` function does, you'll at least want ".mp4" to be a string:

```
<button onclick='download(this, ".mp4")' type="button">Download</button>
```

So you'll want your PHP to read:

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick='download(this, \"$ext\")'>Download</button>";
```

Comment: echoing from a php script into a html page it strips off the "''" ... leaving it to be .mp4

Comment: Then you might want to show us the PHP; it's definitely a problem that needs to be fixed.